# Preg_split sentences inside an array keeping punctuation

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have a text like this:
**"this is sentence 1. this is sentence 2. is this sentence 3? hello world!"**

I use this code to split the text into sentences and insert them in an array.

```
 $content = $page_data->post_content;
   $sentence = preg_split('/[!?\.]\s?/', $content);
   $sentence = array_map('trim', $sentence);
   echo $sentence[0]; - **which renders this is sentence 1 - without the "."**
   ....
```

How can I use this code and keep the punctuation?

Ty:)

Comment: In Perl’s `split`, you can keep your separators by using capture groups, but those show up as separate elements. If that’s what you want, then you could use a global match to effect the same result. But if you want to keep it on the end of the sentence, @codaddict has the right general idea. For real-world data, you will need to be a bit more careful is all. Isn’t there some existing library that does NLP-correct sentence-splitting for you already, like [Perl’s Lingua::Sentence](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua::Sentence)? That’s what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the positive look behind assertion as:

```
$sentence = preg_split('/(?<=[!?.])./', $content);
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/1azGw)

Comment: That won’t work for sentences with abbreviations in them, you know. You need to use something more like `(?<=[!?.])(?:$|\s+(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\b))`, and even then you have a problem with Mr. Rogers and such. You should probably use a stoplist for frequently abbreviated titles, but you won’t get good results without running it through a machine-learning engine on a corpus that resembles your input stream to train it about such things.

Answer (score 0):

preg_split has no such flag, which keeps the delimiter, but, you can use preg_match_all:

```
<?php

    $content = "this is sentence 1. this is sentence 2. is this sentence 3? hello world!";
    preg_match_all('/([^\.\?!]+[\.\?!])/', $content, $sentence);
    $sentence = array_map('trim', $sentence[0]);
    print_r($sentence);

?>
```